# UINavigationBar Background Color Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios-animations

I am trying to implement Apple's detail screen from their Podcast, Music, and App Store Apps. The navigation bar starts off transparent then increases the alpha the further down you scroll.

I have the desired effect working changing the alpha value of the navigationBar itself. However, this also affects the buttons within the navigationBar.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 350
    if offset > 1 {
        offset = 1
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = offset
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: false)
    } else {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = offset
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

I believe I need to change either

1. The Navigation Bar's backgroundColor
2. The Navigation Bar's barTintColor

Upon implementing each of these and replacing:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = offset
```

with

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Color.background?.withAlphaComponent(offset)
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = Color.background?.withAlphaComponent(offset)
```

The animation does not transition, it simply goes from transparent to opaque.

I am setting up my Navigation Bar on this controller using iOS 13 methods

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect of a smoothly transitioning navigation bar while maintaining button visibility, you might consider using a combination of alpha adjustments for the background and manipulating the button's visibility separately.

Here's a suggestion:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 350
    
    if offset > 1 {
        updateNavigationBar(withAlpha: 1)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        updateNavigationBar(withAlpha: offset)
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    }
}

func updateNavigationBar(withAlpha alpha: CGFloat) {
    let backgroundColor = Color.background?.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
    
    // Update background with a fade animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    }
    
    // Update only the background alpha without affecting the buttons
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = alpha
}
```

This separates the handling of background transparency (with a fade animation for a smoother transition) from the adjustment of the navigation bar's alpha to maintain button visibility. Adjust the duration of the animation (animate(withDuration: 0.3)) as needed for the desired effect.